# Cannot save Bitmap image to Phone's Storage in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, android-gallery, android-file

So, I am creating a QRCode generator application in which user can generate QR code from the data they have entered.I can successfully generate the QR code and show it to the imageview on a Button click but I am facing issue when I tried to save that QR code to my phone's storage (or gallery).

On this button click, QRGenerator function will be called and It will generate the QR code from the Edittext data.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               QRGenerator();
            }
        });
```

Here is the QRGenerator() funcion :

```
private void QRGenerator() {
        String data = text.getText().toString();
        MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
        try {
            BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300);
            BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
            Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
            imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)imgView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
            saveImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (WriterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and from here I can call the save image function :

```
saveImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                saveImageFunction(bitmap2);
            }
        });
```

and here my issue arise, I have put a Toast to notify when my image will saved to gallery but it never pops up

Here is the saveImageFunction :

```
private void saveImageFunction(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String savedImagePath = null;
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "test" + ".jpg";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/Demo");
        boolean success = true;
        if(!storageDir.exists()){
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if(success){
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
            savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            addToGallery(savedImagePath);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Saved to Gallery!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

and to put that saved image to gallery I have used this function :

addToGallery() :

```
private void addToGallery(String imagePath){
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(imagePath);
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
    }
```

As per Gk Mohammad Emon says, I tried adding Toast as well as Log.d in my catch method of SaveImage function but nothing pops up neither on Screen nor in LogCat (Please address any type of mistake if there) :

```
 private void saveImageFunction(Bitmap bitmap) {
        String savedImagePath = null;
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + "test" + ".jpg";
        File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+ "/Demo");
        boolean success = true;
        if(!storageDir.exists()){
            success = storageDir.mkdirs();
        }
        if(success){
            File imageFile = new File(storageDir, imageFileName);
            savedImagePath = imageFile.getAbsolutePath();
            try {
                OutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Image Saved!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                fOut.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"hello There",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d("Exception e",e.toString());
            }
            addToGallery(savedImagePath);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Saved to Gallery!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a toast also in catch to get the proper exception and mention in here.

Comment: Noting happens, I tried to add both Toast and Log.d in catch block but when I press the SaveImage button, neither Toast nor Log pops up. (in logcat), I have updated my code and edited my post

Comment: `but nothing pops up neither on Screen nor in LogCat`. Ok. But what does that mean? You are not telling that.     You should display a Toast when mkdirs returns false.

Comment: Even if there is a catch (in the last code) you add the path to the list. That makes no sense. Please adapt.

Comment: I cannot understand what you guys are saying... Please can someone show it with an example or something?

Comment: I'm sure boolean "success' is being  false here. that means it cannot making the directory named "/demo".